# Reduce the memory when converting csv file to excel with CsvHelper

Tags: c#, excel, csv, csvhelper

When we convert csv file to excel by using **CSVHelper** with 100K rows and 14 columns it takes 1.5GB process memory. We need to reduce the memory. Is that a issue of CsvHelper, taking that much of memory to convert file or are we doing anything wrong here. Is there a workaround for this to reduce the memory.

Here's an example program I am using:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using CsvHelper;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp2.Conversion
{
    public class CsvHelperExcelWriter
    {
        public void Process(string csvFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
                using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(XLEventTracking.Disabled))
                {
                    var _worksheet = workbook.AddWorksheet("Sheet1");
                    using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(csvFilePath), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    {
                        csv.Read();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(csv.Context.Parser.RawRecord))
                        {
                            AddHeaders(csv, _worksheet);
                            AddValues(csv, _worksheet);
                        }
                    }
                    workbook.SaveAs(ms);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\Projects\\POC\\SampleFile\\Excel\\100000 Sales Records with CsvHelper.xlsx", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        ms.CopyTo(fileStream);
                        fileStream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private void AddValues(CsvReader csv, IXLWorksheet _worksheet)
        {
            int rowNumber = 2;
            while (csv.Read())
            {
                int cellNumber = 1;
                for (var i = 0; csv.TryGetField(i, out string value); i++)
                {
                    _worksheet.Cell(rowNumber, cellNumber).SetValue(value);
                    cellNumber++;
                }
                rowNumber++;
            }
        }

        private void AddHeaders(CsvReader csv, IXLWorksheet _worksheet)
        {
            int index = 1;
            _ = csv.ReadHeader();
            foreach (var header in csv.HeaderRecord)
            {
                _worksheet.Cell(1, index).Value = header;
                index++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a MemoryStream just to save it to a file, when workbook.SaveAs() already allows a filename to be passed.

Comment: You may want to add a ClosedXML tag, since that is what you are using

Comment: CsvHelper will yield records so you only have a small buffer of memory used as you're reading through the rows. ClosedXML has several bugs filed with large memory consumption. Check with them or possibly try a different Excel library.

Answer (score 1):

Typically high memory usage is because of final XML serialization that is used by all Excel libraries when creating a XLSX file. To resolve this issues I ended with creating my own `SwiftExcel` library that outputs data directly to the file omitting actual XML serialization.

In your case I would recommend to read the CSV with something efficient like [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) and then output it with [SwiftExcel](https://github.com/RomanPavelko/SwiftExcel).

Here is an example. Read your CSV first with `ExcelDataReader` and collect all data:

```
var list = new List<List<string>>();
using (var stream = File.Open("C:\\temp\\input.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateCsvReader(stream))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var subList = new List<string>();
            for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                subList.Add(reader.GetValue(i)?.ToString());
            }
            list.Add(subList);
        }
    }
}
```

And now output this data into Excel using `SwiftExcel`:

```
using (var ew = new ExcelWriter("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx"))
{
    for (var row = 1; row <= list.Count; row++)
    {
        var subList = list[row-1];
        for (var col = 1; col <= subList.Count; col++)
        {
            ew.Write(subList[col-1], col, row);
        }
    }
}
```

There is still a memory concern because you collect all CSV data first but at least it is no so high as using XML serialization. You can try to eliminate that by merging these 2 loops into one and output value at the same moment when you read it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with C#. But if I were to guess the problem, its probably reading everything at once and keeping it in memory. You should use some kind of buffered approach where whole csv file is not loaded at once in memory. And once you tranform the csv row, you have to make sure that you output it immediately to excel file and discard csv row(not store it in any array/list) so it can be picked up by garabage collector.